# How to show SwiftUI preview in landscape

Tags: swiftui-previews

.previewLayout(.fixed(width: 480, height: 320)) has no effect in Xcode 13.4 and Xcode 14 beta 3

The preview is shown in portrait vs expected landscape
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it clear here, you did not actually set your `preview` in landscape mode. Two solutions for your problem:

1. You actually requested the preview to be in a fixed size window, so to make this work, you need to choose `Selectable` in the canvas window to preview in a fixed sized window. I have drawn a red line around that part in the attached image. (code and image are below)

[image]

```
FContentView() //fixed size window
        .previewLayout(.fixed(width: 480, height: 320))
```

2. If you want to actually preview in a landscape mode, use `.previewInterfaceOrientation(.landscapeLeft)` or right. You can choose either live / selectable. (code and image are below)

[image]

```
FContentView() //real landscape view
        .previewInterfaceOrientation(.landscapeLeft)
```