# Display View In Blank Canvas

Tags: xcode, swiftui

Hello heroes of the internet,

When we develop apps on Xcode we can preview apps on the Canvas, and it looks something like this:

[image]

Luckily, SwiftUI allows for splitting up the code in an easy manner, with "Views". Say you have a simple view and you want to preview it on a blank canvas, not on the phone with the phone's aspect ratio and notch and all that. I want to display my view in a simple blank canvas, like in the image below.

[image]
How can I do such thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change to the `selectable` preview mode at the bottom of the canvas:

[image]

Then add this to the preview code:

```
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
            ContentView()
            .previewLayout(.sizeThatFits) // here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, set up your preview layout in a fixed frame like below:

```
struct FContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider { //don't forget to change name
 static var previews: some View { //don't forget to change name
    FContentView()
        .previewLayout(.fixed(width: 480, height: 320)) //this line of code
 }
}
```

Then, set the preview option to `Selectable` like the below image.

You can also refer to my latest updated answer: [fixed frame preview in canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73121105/how-to-show-swiftui-preview-in-landscape/73123595#73123595)

[image]